# Shortest distance of a location from a route (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, latitude-longitude, shapely, shortest

I have a location with its lat and long information

```
loc = (28.469723, 77.065292)
```

and a route (polyline) given by five lat long pairs

```
route = [(28.478324, 77.093916), (28.471647, 77.092457), (28.465498, 77.086105), (28.461273, 77.077651)]
```

Is there a simple way to calculate the shortest distance in km from `loc` to `route`?

Answer (score 0):

Then you could solve it like that.

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, LinearRing

loc = (28.469723, 77.065292)
routePoints = [(28.478324, 77.093916), (28.471647, 77.092457), (28.465498, 77.086105), (28.461273, 77.077651)]

point = Point(loc)
route = LineString(routePoints)

pol_ext = LinearRing(route.coords)
d = pol_ext.project(point)
p = pol_ext.interpolate(d)
closest_point_coords = list(p.coords)[0]

distance = vincenty(closest_point_coords, loc).km

print(distance)
```

1.5303772782641438

The output is still the same because the point is accidentally the nearest, but by changing the point you will see that it finds a point on the line that is closest.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this will give me the distance from nearest out of these five coordinates... What I need is the shortest distance from the path given by these points.